# Excel VBA inconsistent behaviour while trying to implement a tree view

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub myfunction()
    Dim convert_i, convert_k As String
    Dim i, j, k, l As Long

    For i = 2 To 583
        For k = i + 1 To 583
            j = InStr(Range("F" & k).Text, Range("F" & i).Text)
            If j > 0 Then
                l = InStr(Range("F" & k).Text, " \ ")
                If l > 1 Then
                    convert_i = Range("F" & i).Text & ""
                    convert_k = Range("F" & k).Text & ""
                    pos = InStrRev(convert_k, convert_i) - 1
                    Range("F" & k).Value = Right(convert_k, Len(convert_i) - pos)
                    Range("F" & k).Value = Range("F" & i).Text + Range("F" & k).Text
                Else:
                    Range("F" & k).Value = Range("F" & i).Value + " \ " + Range("F" & k).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Finished ")
End Sub
```

The code works for the most part however it's inconsistent and I'm baffled as to why. The desired result is like

```
CP \ CP01 \ CP0103
```

And through the document I think like at least a good 70 percent is of this format but I do not have the time to go trough remaining 30 percent manually. I would very much appreciate any help.

Please check images below:

[image]

[image]

The expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnh0G.png)

Comment: Is the 2nd image the expected result or what you are currently getting? If it's the latter what is the expected result.

Comment: The 2nd image is what I'm getting the expected result is like CP \ CP01 \ CP0103 .

Comment: There's no way we can fix this without the source data. Add a breakpoint to the code, step through it, inspect the variables, and see where it goes wrong. Are the values in the variables what you expect? Is there a flaw in the branching logic?

Comment: don't you want: `Range("F" & k).Value = Range("F" & i).Text & " / "  & Range("F" & k).Text` instead of `Range("F" & k).Value = Range("F" & i).Text + Range("F" & k).Text`?

Comment: @ScottCraner That caused double " \ ".   https://imgur.com/B6WDAW4 , I think there is more than one problem in my code.

Comment: Could you share all the desired values expected from the first image?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have updated my post with the 3rd picture.

Comment: That 3rd image looks as though all you want to do is prefix all the values after row 2 with 'CP\  CP01 \ '.

Comment: @norie please note, the file has near 600 lines there is also CP02, example: CP \ CP02 \  CP020402

Comment: Your dimensioning... `Dim i, j, k, l As Long` tells the system that you have `i as variant`, `j as variant`, `k as variant`, and `l as long`; you need to be specific with VBA, same for your `as string` dimensioning.

Comment: @Cyril thanks for letting me know, though it didn't have any effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Tree

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createTree()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const First As String = "F2"
    Const len1 As Long = 2
    Const len2 As Long = 4
    Const Sep As String = " \ "
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(First)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value ' assuming there is data in F3 at least
    Dim sLen As Long: sLen = Len(Sep)
    Dim tLen As Long: tLen = len1 + sLen + len2
    
    Dim cString As String
    Dim cPref1 As String
    Dim cPref2 As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        cString = Trim(Data(r, 1))
        Select Case Len(cString)
        Case len1
            cPref1 = cString
            cPref2 = ""
            Data(r, 1) = cString
        Case len2
            cPref2 = cPref1 & Sep & cString
            Data(r, 1) = cPref2
        Case Else
            If Len(cPref2) = tLen Then
                cPref2 = cPref2 & Sep & cString
            Else
                cPref2 = Left(cPref2, tLen) & Sep & cString
            End If
            Data(r, 1) = cPref2
        End Select
    Next r
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, this works very well for the data I provided. Though it didn't work for all elements but it looks much better to work on than buggy mid, right and left. After I study the code hopefully I will be able to tell you about combinations that resulted in some unexpected results. Much respect!

Comment: Length based approach is not suitable for my use case unfortunately. Not all elements are of the lengths 2 and 4.

Comment: Good to know. Any new info on your use case? There has to be a certain logic about it. I mean with a few changes it surely can be adapted to fit your needs. Try using relevant screenshots and give it a try to explain better. You could maybe upload your workbook and post a link for downloading. Otherwise, maybe try asking a new question. You can add a link to it somewhere in the comments on this page to attract interested parties since there was quite a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub myfunction()
    Dim convert_i, convert_k, last_part As String
    Dim i, j, k, l As Long

    For i = 2 To 583
        For k = i + 1 To 583
            j = InStr(Range("F" & k).Text, Range("F" & i).Text)
            If j > 0 Then
                l = InStrRev(Range("F" & k).Text, " \ ")
                If l > 0 Then
                    convert_i = Range("F" & i).Value
                    convert_k = Range("F" & k).Value
                    
                    last_part = Right(convert_k, Len(convert_k) - l - 2)
                    
                    Range("F" & k).Value = Range("F" & i).Text & " \ " & last_part
                Else:
                    Range("F" & k).Value = Range("F" & i).Value & " \ " & Range("F" & k).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Finished ")
End Sub
```

I realised my implementation was terrible, I was confused by getting it almost 70 percent right. The above code got the job done. Might as well delete the question as I don't think it would be of help to anybody.